# Jmeter Create JDBC Connection Configuration instance in java code

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter

I Would like to ask if there is a way to create instance of JDBC Connection Configuration for JMeter by code and not via GUI .

i have The following threadGroup :

```
SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(jMeterParam.getNumOfConnections());
        threadGroup.setRampUp(0);
        threadGroup.setDuration(7200);



    JDBCSampler sampler = new JDBCSampler();
    sampler.setQuery("select top 1 * from Production.ProductPhoto;");
    sampler.setVariableNames("firstPrfile");
    sampler.setQueryType("Select Statement");
    ConstantTimer timer = new ConstantTimer();
    timer.setDelay("300");
```

I need to create instance of JDBCConnectionConfiguration in order to set JMeter variable name , max number of connections , pool timeout , and all avilable parameters in JDBC Connection Configuration JMeter GUI .

---

The issue that i need to write java code in order configure Test Plan and run it via JMeter .
i have tried your suggestion to create JDBC connection as bellow :

```
SetupThreadGroup threadGroup = new SetupThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(jMeterParam.getNumOfConnections());
        threadGroup.setRampUp(0);
        threadGroup.setDuration(7200);
        DefaultPoolController defaultPoolController = new DefaultPoolController();

        JdbcConnectionFactory jdbcFactory = new JdbcConnectionFactory("jdbc:sqlserver://10.10.10.171:1401;databaseName=AdventureWorks","sa","1q@W3e4r",true,"True","com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        JdbcConnectionPool jdbcConnPool= new JdbcConnectionPool(jdbcFactory,defaultPoolController,0,10,true);


        JDBCSampler sampler = new JDBCSampler();
        sampler.setQuery("select top 1 * from Production.ProductPhoto;");
        sampler.setVariableNames("firstPrfile");
        sampler.setQueryType("Select Statement");
        ConstantTimer timer = new ConstantTimer();
        timer.setDelay("300");


        sampler.addTestElement(timer);

        // Test plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("MY TEST PLAN");
        hashTree.add("testPlan", testPlan);
        hashTree.add("threadGroup", threadGroup);
        hashTree.add("JDBC Connection Configuration", jdbcConnPool);
        hashTree.add("sampler", sampler);

        jm.configure(hashTree);

        jm.run();
```

When running WARN MSG shown : 
1) "Something bad happened when loading bean info for bean class org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.sampler.JDBCSampler" 
2) Did not find ".....ApacheJMeter.jar/commons-io-2.2.jar/etc ....

Do You know How to Solve it ?

Thanks A lot,
Khilo

Answer (score 0):

I personally create my test via JMeter GUI and don't use JMeter API directly. But considering your question I think you can create JDBC connection and perform needed query without instantiating JDBC sampler. Or you can create BSF Sampler and setup connection and query in its body. I did the second way (although I used GUI): created BSF Sampler, connect to DB and perform query, then manipulate data using Groovy.